# Print.exe randomly gives Unable to initialize device error message

Tags: .net, web-services, iis, networking, printing

We created an IIS web service that starts a print.exe process to submit print jobs over network to shared printers in different locations. Normally this process works fine and **prn** are being sent to remote printers successfully.

However, sometimes print.exe returns "*Unable to initialize device \\server_name\shared_printer_name*" and I am totally unable to track what is going on and I can' t create this case manually.

Can you help me understand what the problem can be? What can I check to understand and resolve this issue?

Web service starts the process with the following code:

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "print.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/D:\"" + printerName + "\" " + prnFilePath;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process printProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
    bool printSuccessful = false;
    while (!printProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = printProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        log.Debug("Response of print process: " + line);
        if (line.Contains("currently being printed"))
        {
            printSuccessful = true;
        }
    }
    return printSuccessful;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("printWithWindowsCommand failed. Could not print", ex);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue occurs when the web service is called multiple times at the same moment. When the web service is invoked with two requests at the same time, one of these requests succeeds and the another one fails.

To overcome this, I changed the print.exe process starting part, and instead of this, I just **COPY /B** the file to the printer spool. That can be used concurrently by different processes without any issue.